# Select two sets of information using AngularJS select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, firebase

I need to get two option from my database using select. 
I have in my Firebase this information:

```
 dias: "3"
 nome: "VISA - DEBITO"
 taxa: "1,11"
 tipo: "001"
```

and I'm using this line in HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Formas <span class="text-danger" style="font-size: 15px;">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select chosen="{width: '100%'}" name="formas" class="form-control" id="formas" ng-options="item2.dias as item2.nome for item2 in childformas" ng-model="ordem.formaId" data-placeholder="Escolha a forma de pagamento">
          <option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The result of this is I take the `dias` info selecting `VISA - DEBITO` `ordem.formaId` -> 3, but I need to get at the same time the info of `dias` and `taxa`.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: HI! Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you use the {} button to format your code?

Answer (score 0):

you should look into this documentation about directives then you can assign dias and taxa to their own custom attribute.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.